# Mysql left join with double same-table relation where clause

Tags: mysql, join, select, relation

Basically I have these 2 simple mysql tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `relation` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tier` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'same table'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `relation`) VALUES
(12, 'user1', 5),
(20, 'user2', NULL),
(21, 'user3', NULL);

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `user`, `data`, `tier`, `parent_id`) VALUES
(1, 12, 'test1', 1, NULL),
(2, 20, 'test2', 2, 1),
(3, 21, 'test3', 3, 1),
(4, 20, 'test4', 1, NULL);
```

I need to select all rows from 'mytable' that are related with the **users.relation = 5**

To do that I use the following query:

```
SELECT mytable.*
FROM mytable
    LEFT JOIN users ON mytable.user = users.id
WHERE users.relation = 5
```

The problem is that I also need to select the rows from `mytable` that have a **parent_id** connected with the above results.

```
WHERE mytable.id = X OR mytable.parent_id = X
```

Basically in this example, the expected output should be all rows of mytable except the last one 
(because is not connected with users.relation = 5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another join of `mytable` to your query:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM mytable m INNER JOIN (
  SELECT m.* 
  FROM mytable m 
  INNER JOIN users u ON m.user = u.id 
  WHERE u.relation = 5
) t ON t.id IN (m.id, m.parent_id)
```

I changed the join to `INNER` join, because although you use `LEFT` join the `WHERE` clause changes it to `INNER` since it filters out any unmatched rows.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d70ae4aabb752261650ccaf4d427e95e).
Results:

```
> id | user | data  | tier | parent_id
> -: | ---: | :---- | ---: | --------:
>  1 |   12 | test1 |    1 |      null
>  2 |   20 | test2 |    2 |         1
>  3 |   21 | test3 |    3 |         1
```